# SQL extracting information from columns names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with column names such as `INT115`, `INT430` and so on with their corresponding data. I want to multiply data in INT115 column with 115, data in INT430 column with 430 and so on. I am not sure how to proceed.

Edit: I need to parse the column names and get rid of left 3 characters to come up with the multiplier number.

Edit2: I am working with grandfathered table so I can't make changes to how the database looks like.

Comment: Column names which contains some data  - not a good approach. Exhibit A: you already have problem to continue work

Comment: You might need dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: You should read up on database normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit after question was updated

This does not require any hard coding at all:
You could cursor through a temp table that parsed through the column names to get the multiplication values, then SELECT from your table and which would give you the multiplied values. I am using 'sampletable' as your table name. This assumes each of the columns begin with INT and then immediately have a number after.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME, 4, 10)as INT) as multiplier_number 
    INTO #values FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sampletable'

DECLARE @sSql nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @columnname nvarchar(50)

DECLARE thing CURSOR
    FOR
        (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM #values
        )
OPEN thing
FETCH NEXT FROM thing
    INTO @columnname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    Set @sSql = 'SELECT ' + @columnname + '* (SELECT multiplier_number FROM #values where column_name = '''+ @columnname+''') as '+@columnname+' FROM sampletable'

EXEC sp_Executesql @sSql

FETCH NEXT FROM thing into @columnname
END
CLOSE THING
DEALLOCATE THING
```

Comment: Sorry I changed the question as I figured it might lead to hardcoded answers like yours. But thanks for effort.

Comment: But how will you know that the column has `15` or `115` with it?

Comment: I updated my answer so no hardcoding is required. I parse the column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the values to use with the multiplication eg. INT115 has multiplication value 115, INT99 has 99, etc. for as many columns as you have.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the desired results should look like, but if you don't want to code all the field names, perhaps this can help

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,INT115 int,INT430 int,INT550 int)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,25,75,18),
(2,10,1,22)

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * from @YourTable for XML RAW)

;with cteBase as (
    Select ID      = r.value('@ID','int')
          ,Item    = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value   = attr.value('.','varchar(250)') 
     From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
     Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="ID"]') as B(attr)
)
Select ID
      ,Item
      ,OldValue = value
      ,NewValue = cast(Right(Item,3) as int)*Value
 From cteBase
 Where Item Like 'INT___'
```

Returns

```
ID  Item    OldValue    NewValue
1   INT115  25          2875
1   INT430  75          32250
1   INT550  18          9900
2   INT115  10          1150
2   INT430  1           430
2   INT550  22          12100
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the best way but it will give the required result.

```
USE MASTER;
CREATE TABLE table1
(
INT115 int,
INT430 int,
INT1000 int
)

Insert into table1 values (1, 1, 1);
Insert into table1 values (10, 10, 10);

DECLARE @MyTable VARCHAR(100) = 'table1'
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COLS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''


SELECT @COLS = @COLS + ', ' + COLUMN_NAME + '*' + STUFF(COLUMN_NAME, 1, 3, '') + ' AS '+ COLUMN_NAME
FROM master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @MyTable

DECLARE @COLNAMES VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF(@COLS, 1, 1, '')

SET @cmd = 'SELECT '+ @COLNAMES+ ' FROM '  + @MyTable
EXEC (@cmd)
```

OUTPUT:

```
INT115  INT430  INT1000
---------------------
115     430     1000
1150    4300    10000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a simple select statement such as follows:

```
select col1*15 as <heading>, col2*30 as <heading> 
from <schema>.<tablename>
```

e.g.

```
$ db2 "create table test(col15 int, col30 int)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 "insert into test values (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 "select col15*15, col30*30 from test"

1           2
----------- -----------
         15          30
         30          60
         45          90

  3 record(s) selected.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to parse the multiplier value from your column names:

```
SELECT RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', name) + 1)
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourtablenamehere')
```

I wish I knew more but I hope this piece can help!